# With cygwin, what package is lint located in? I could not find it, have code failing because it requires lint

Tags: cygwin

For a project I need to install a Javascript/node package from Mapbox.  Their API's, scripts only work on Linux, I am using cygwin.

It has a dependency on lint.exe, I cannot find it in any cygwin pacakge (when I search in the installer and on the website).

Answer (score 1):

Use `splint` package

http://splint.org/

> Splint is a tool for statically checking C programs for security
>   vulnerabilities and coding mistakes. With minimal effort, Splint can
>   be used as a better lint. If additional effort is invested adding
>   annotations to programs, Splint can perform stronger checking than can
>   be done by any standard lint.